# running laravel queue with multiple database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue, multi-tenant

I have Laravel 5 project. This is multi-tenant project, so I have one folder project with multiple databases.

When I use `php artisan queue:listen`, it only works with the current database setup. I use the `database` queue driver, so each tenant has their own notifications table. How do I setup a queue listener to check all database jobs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to continue using the `database` driver, I would suggest setting up another database that contains all your queued jobs and failed jobs.

Although it is not in the config or mentioned by the documentation, after taking a look at the code, it looks like you should be able to add a `connection` parameter to your queue configuration, and then the queue will interact with the database specified by that connection.

So, in your `config/database.php`, define a new connection for your queue database:

```
'connections' => [
    // your existing connections

    'queue' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'database' => 'your-queue-database',
        // rest of connection information (host, port, etc)
    ],
],
```

Then, in your `config/queue.php`, tell your database queue to use your new connection:

```
'connections' => [
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'connection' => 'queue', // connection name from database config
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
]
```

The other option would be to move to another queue driver. Setup redis, sqs, or beanstalk.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer.. both work, but when i use `redis` how to see current pending job or failed-job like in `database`. so i know if there is something wrong or some job not work as expected ? btw, i use laravel forge for server setup.

Comment: @martiendt No matter which type of queue you use, failed jobs will be reported to the `failed_jobs` table in your database when they exceed the max number of attempts allowed by the queue worker.

Comment: so when i choose to use redis, i need to setup my queue database too ? ok thanks @patricus i'll try it

Comment: Jobs are created as configured, but when listener executes, it connections with default connection always, how to configure dynamic connection for queue listener ?

Comment: Why this is not working for me? In my case worker still tries to fetch jobs from default database connection