# Single Queue run for all tenant database

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

Facing issue with Laravel queue, I have one master database and their tenant database and all tenant database has "jobs" table.
This command runs only for the default set connection "php artisan queue: work", but I want to do it for all other customer's databases.

So it's Possible to single Queue worker-run for all tenant databases?

thanks in advance...

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41318374/6309457         also you can use `redis`

Comment: yes, it has worked fine but I have no database connection for all tenant's databases. I think I need to store jobs in sapetare database or master database.